# Custom tab contents are not changing in SAP B1

Tags: sapb1

On sales order form, if we move back and forth to traverse all sales orders, tab (custom) contents (matrix data) are not changing. How can we change tab contents ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, SAP just handle dbdatasources from tables related to the form type, if your table's matrix is not related to ORDR nothing will happen automatically so you have to implement all form events by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the data is refreshed in both the  Form_DataLoadAfter event *and* the  Form_LoadAfter event.
This way, when using the green arrows to navigate, the data is refreshed.

```
 Private Sub Form_DataLoadAfter(ByRef pVal As SAPbouiCOM.BusinessObjectInfo)

        If Me.UIAPIRawForm.Visible = True Then
            If pVal.ActionSuccess = True Then
                refreshMyMatrix()
            End If
        End If

    End Sub



   Private Sub Form_LoadAfter(pVal As SAPbouiCOM.SBOItemEventArg)

        refreshMyMatrix()

    End Sub
```